# Why I should configure a AWS ECS Service with two or more Subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, subnet

Why I should configure an AWS ECS Service or an EC2 Instance with two or more Private Subnets from the same VPC? What would be the benefits of doing such thing instead of configuring it within just one Subnet? Would it be because of availability? I've read the documentation but it was not clear about it.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is generally to distribute your ECS service across multiple availability zones, allowing your service to maintain high availability.

A subnet is bound to a single AZ, so it is assumed each subnet is in a **different AZ**.

By splitting across multiple subnets, during an outage load can be shifted to launch containers entirely in other subnets (assuming they're in different AZs).

This is generally encouraged for all services that support multiple availability zones.

More information on [Amazon ECS Availability best practices](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-ecs-availability-best-practices/) are available from the blog.

Comment: So, basically, if we configure an ECS service with two Subnets and both of them in different AZs, if something happens within the AZ1, for instance, the other AZ2 would be there to guarantee the access to ECS service?

Comment: Yes. If you're using Fargate this will happen automatically, if you're EC2 based and not using dynamic port ranges then ensure that you use autoscaling groups spread across the AZs too :)